# openCL "Arguments mismatch for instruction 'mov'" error

Tags: error-handling, compilation, opencl, gpu, nvidia

So one of my devices (a Nvidia GeForce GT 650m GPU) keeps giving me this weird ptxas application error saying "Arguments mismatch for instruction 'mov' when I try to build a cl_program on that device. It's the only one of my 3 devices that gives me this error. My CPU and other GPU (Intel HD 4000) do not give me this error at all.

Here's an example of a function that causes this error to happen. It's a helper function I use inside one of my kernels:

```
//Calculate the dot product of two vectors
float Dot(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    return (v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y + v1.z*v2.z);
}
```

First I tried splitting up the work into something like this:

```
//Calculate the dot product of two vectors)
float Dot(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    float a = v1.x*v2.x;
    float b = v1.y*v2.y;
    float c = v1.z*v2.z;
    float result = a + b + c;
    return result;
}
```

But that also gives me the same error. Interestingly enough, if I simply set result = 5.0f and return that it magically compiles and runs:

```
//THIS WILL COMPILE AND RUN
float Dot(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    float a = v1.x*v2.x;
    float b = v1.y*v2.y;
    float c = v1.z*v2.z;
    float result = 5.0f; //IGNORE THE CALCULATION. JUST MAKE IT 5
    return result;
}
```

So I have no idea what's going on. My 'Dot' function isn't the only function that's affected but one of several. Is my Nvidia card defective?

**EDIT** Here is the log I get from clGetProgramBuildInfo after the build fails:

```
ptxas application ptx input, line 703; error   : Arguments mismatch for instruction 'mov'
ptxas application ptx input, line 703; error   : Unknown symbol 'LIntersection_2E_n'
ptxas application ptx input, line 703; error   : Label expected for forward reference of     'LIntersection_2E_n'
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

Although there are more errors printed than just the 'mov' one I described, they all go away when I make the above change of result = 5.0f;

Comment: Looks like the compiler might be generating incorrect PTX code. Could you paste the generated PTX?

Comment: @Cicada, I posted the PTX

Comment: If you set it to 5, the compiler is intelligent enough to simplify your code as `float Dot(Vector v1, Vector v2){return 5.0f;};` so is logical that the error goes away. If you disable compiler optimizations probably the error will stay.  But, what is your "Vector"? Can you post the definition of it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the LLVM developers, this is a bug in the nvptx back-end.

[LLVMdev forum message discussing this error](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-July/051862.html)